# Browser based software for simple HTML poster design

Tags: gratis, php, html-editor, templating, visual-design

As part of a PHP based application which I have to develop, I have been asked to incorporate a feature which allows non-tech-savvy users to make a simple advertising poster, just some text & maybe images, possibly by choosing from a few templates, possibly by drag/drop almost like a drawing program.

I have argued that the user should use an external web page design program and then import it into my app, but to no avail.

using templates could be simple enough, drag/drop like a drawing program would require more effort on my part.

Is there any existing gratis software that would let me incorporate simple poster design into my PHP application?

Comment: Fabric.js is a JS library which allows you to build your designer around it. See a previous answer of mine: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11481/583

Comment: @ComFreek that is exactly what I want. If you post it as an answer then I will award you the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

- Provides rich functionality around a drawing `<canvas>`.
- Objects (shapes) can be moved, scaled and rotated. Text fields and images are such objects, for instance.
- Drag and Drop with canvas-external objects can be easily implemented. I've once done it with images which can be moved onto the canvas via the mouse.
- Loading the state from JSON and saving to it is possible. This method could be used for your templates: When loading the site or when clicking a reset button, the program would just reload the default JSON data.

Further possibilities are outlined in another answer of mine: [Custom drawing tool with HTML Canvas](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11481/583)